# how set excel range from the third row

Tags: delphi

This code works fine if MyRange is set from the first row.
How omit 2 rows, add something like this code in my main code

> ExcelApp.Cells.Item[1,1].Value:= 'text on the first row';
> ExcelApp.Cells.Item[2,1].Value:= FormatDateTime('dd/mm/yyyy', Now);

so that MyRange begin not from the first but **from the third row**?

Thanks in advance.

```
procedure TfMain.miExcelClick(Sender: TObject);
  var
  ExcelApp: Variant;
  MyRange:OleVariant;
  col, row,i,j: Integer;
  sline: string;
  mem: TMemo;
begin
  ExcelApp := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
  ExcelApp.WorkBooks.Add; 
  ExcelApp.WorkBooks[1].WorkSheets[1].name := 'Grid Data';

  mem := TMemo.Create(Self);
  mem.Visible := false;
  mem.Parent := fMain;
  mem.Clear;
  sline := '';

  for j :=0 to dbgrid1.FieldCount-1 do
    sline := sline + dbgrid1.Columns[j].Title.Caption + #9; 
  mem.Lines.Add(sline);

  // получаем данные из memo
  for row := 0 to dbgrid1.DataSource.DataSet.RecordCount-1 do
  begin
    sline := '';
    for col := 0 to dbgrid1.FieldCount-1 do
      sline := sline + dbgrid1.Fields[col].AsString + #9;
    mem.Lines.Add(sline);
    dbgrid1.DataSource.DataSet.Next;
  end;

  // copy data to clipboard
  mem.SelectAll;
  mem.CopyToClipboard;

  ExcelApp.Workbooks[1].WorkSheets['Grid Data'].Paste;
  ExcelApp.Visible := true;

  MyRange:= ExcelApp.Range['A1',ExcelApp.Cells.Item[row+1,col]];
```

Comment: Why can't you just change the numbers where you set the range? Did you write this code yourself? Or did you just copy/paste it from somewhere?

Comment: Also, see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20303227/62576) for an example of quickly moving data from a database table to Excel properly. You don't need to make everything one long string with separators - you can move data directly and keep the proper data types.

Comment: Just change 'A1' to 'A3'?

Comment: @KenWhite thank you for you comment. similar code works fine in case of slow TExcelApplication component. I don't know why doesn't work  wirh  vararray.  I change A1 with A3 but without result- always get range on the first row.  Now I change code with your link  and I get rnge from third row but  now didn't get data. There are simplified code. What is wrong in it?

Comment: query1.Close;
  query1.Open;

  Row := query1.RecordCount;
  Col := query1.FieldCount;
  arrData := VarArrayCreate([1, Row, 1, Col], varVariant);

  for i:=1 to row do begin
   for j:=1 to Col do
    arrData[i,j] := query1.Fields[j-1].Value;
    query1.Next;
  end;

  xls := CreateOLEObject('Excel.Application');
  wb := xls.Workbooks.Add;

  wb.WorkSheets[1].Cells[1,1].Value:= 'Header';

Comment: for j:=1 to col do
    WB.Worksheets.Application.Cells.Item[2,j]:= query1.Columns[j-1].Title.Caption;

  Range := wb.WorkSheets[1].Range[wb.WorkSheets[1].Cells[4, 1],
                                  wb.WorkSheets[1].Cells[Row, Col]];
  Range.Value := arrData;
  xls.Visible := True;

Comment: When I look at your original code again, I notice that you _first_ Paste (to Worksheets[1.], which I think is the top left corner, i.e. at A1), and only after that do you set the Range variable, which you then never use. Don't you want to change to row 3 already when you Paste? Also, when you calculate Range, you make it from A1 to ExcelApp.Cells....  - shouldn't that be ExcelApp.Worksheets['Grid Data'].Cells..... ?

Comment: Would this work: ExcelApp.Workbooks[1].WorkSheets['Grid Data'].Cells[3, 1].Paste?

Comment: @MatthiasB you are right. It works. Thank you.